# How can I show Contact Form Using Pop up window

Tags: asp.net, popup

Please tell me how I can implement Model Popup window on Contact Form

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery Modal Plugins](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/)

Here is a nice article to show modal in **ASP.NET**

- [Smum County Modal Form for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/SmumModalForm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Which contact form ? If its your custom form, use this function to show it as modal window:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would probably be the [jQuery popup plugin.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popup).  I've used it with some success.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openContactForm(){
   var win = window.open('contactus.aspx','Contact Us','width=200,height=100');
}
</script>

<a href="#" id="contactLink" onclick="open_contactForm()">Contact Us</a>
```

for more options see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) page.